# How Are Titles Written In Japanese?

Tags: nuances, syntax

In English, titles are written with all words being capitalized with exception of certain noteworthy function words. Given this, what are the rules for Japanese titles? I know they exist, titles are clearly written differently; but what exactly are these rules?

Also, if you could give some example titles where these rules are being applied, that would be greatly appreciated. :)

PS. Someone told me that title rules are used when writing news articles as well, like in the body itself; is this true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is almost no rule specific to titles.

- A period is not used because a title is not a sentence.
- If English characters appear in the title, it's typically capitalized just like English titles, although this is not really an ironclad rule.
- If the title is long, typesetters try to avoid breaking a word into two lines. In main text, as you know, you can break words almost freely.
- Word usage itself can also differ. See [what is the name of the abbreviated writing style used in newspapers?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14512/5010)

Of course there are also differences of graphic design. For example, Japanese people love to [decorate titles with fancy borders or frames with an illustration](http://midashi-design.com/).