# What does the phrase "日本アニメ、米中が爆買い　ネット配信の覇権争い過熱" mean?

Tags: translation

Recently, as a way to test my Japanese comprehension, I've been attempting to read articles in Japanese. However, my knowledge of the language is still quite limited and so I have trouble with some phrases and words, and the such.

I saw the title "日本アニメ、米中が爆買い　ネット配信の覇権争い過熱" for an article and have not been able to get a very good grasp on the meaning. Please help?

Comment: Related: [what is the name of the abbreviated writing style used in newspapers?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14559/9831)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you familiar with the newspaper writing style? In headlines in particular, there's a tendency to use heavily abbreviated sentences to convey the relevant information in a compact space (it also sounds more "punchy" this way).

This means using common abbreviations for words (particularly the names of countries, which are generally reduced to their single-kanji abbreviations where possible), leaving out particles that can be understood from context, and making extensive use of the 体言止め technique (ending sentences on a noun and omitting the final verb).

If you were to expand this particular headline into a fully grammatical sentence, it would read something like:

> 日本のアニメ（作品）をアメリカや中国（の人）が爆買いしている。インターネット配信の覇権争いが過熱している。
>   "America and China are buying Japanese anime at an explosive rate. The struggle for superiority in internet streaming is heating up."