# 「電気自動車を一層推進。」 (NounをNoun)

Tags: grammar

> 電気自動車を一層推進。

I'm very confused about the grammar structure in this example.

Here is a list of things that I'm confused abouot:

- Is the structure in this example NounをNoun?
- Was is the する in 推進 omitted?
- How should I use the NounをNoun structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, する, した or しよう has been omitted at the end. In news headlines and such, する is usually omitted to save space.

- [what is the name of the abbreviated writing style used in newspapers?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14512/5010)
- [What does the phrase "日本アニメ、米中が爆買い　ネット配信の覇権争い過熱" mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57166/5010)

English also has a set of tricky rules for headlines ([headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headline#Headlinese)).