# 上陸したよ. Is this slang?? How does it translate to meaningful English? Please see context in body

Tags: translation, slang, puns

[image]

So this literally translates into "I landed it." Which is literally what Kamata-kun (this character from Shin Godzilla) did. But is that really all it means? Is it a Japanese double entendre or pun or have any other connotation other than he came up on land? In English we might say you "landed something" as in you got a good job or achieved something worthwhile. Is that it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't think so.  Seems kind of just like he's saying, "I'm here!"

Comment: Yeah, also seems like that to me. I'm gonna leave slang interpretations (or lack thereof) up to native speakers, but this is intransitive land, not transitive - no "landing it".

Answer (score 2):

> So this literally translates into "I landed it."

More like "I landed". 上陸 sounds like he came out of the sea, since the 上 implies upwards. For example aircraft etc. are 着陸 rather than 上陸.

> In English we might say you "landed something" as in you got a good job or achieved something worthwhile. Is that it?

As far as I know such an expression doesn't exist in Japanese.

Comment: +1. 上陸 does not mean "to finish". (As an aside, 上陸 is used as a catchphrase like [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/72665/5010), in which case whether the product came by air or by sea does not matter.)

Comment: I don't know for sure but I think "I landed something" comes from fishing terminology so it's like 大漁 in Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

Since I haven't watched this movie (I really liked godzilla vs mothra though), I hope I am not missing the context.

I need help of this entry for [蒲田{かまた}くん](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E8%92%B2%E7%94%B0%E3%81%8F%E3%82%93) on ニコニコ大百科. There is a dialog(probably on the scene) on it.

「この巨大不明生物が上陸することはありませんので、どうかご安心ください」:

*"Since this unknown giant creature is not going to land on here, please don't worry about that."*

↓

「え、蒲田{かまた}に？」: *"On Kamata? Really?"*

Reading this dialog, I guess this「蒲田{かまた}くん」was really unlikely to land on Japan, but he landed (maybe done easily because their face seems not be getting exhaust).

So,「上陸したよ」would probably mean "(Don't be surprised!) *I've made it to land here!"*.

The last「よ」is similar to [「ぜ」](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Japanese/Grammar/Sentence_ending_particles#%E3%82%88),but less emphatic.