# How does [発見]{はっけん} function here?

Tags: usage

I couldn't find any explanation online anywhere, and I see it being used a lot as such an expression "[something] [発見]{はっけん}", like "shield is found." in Apex Legends game for example, and in some anime "いい[棒発見]{ぼうはっけん}", being another example.

Isn't it a noun? How is it being used here on its own, instead of its verb form?
Because of its tone I wonder whether it's originally a military expression?

Comment: In a game you'd expect a message that said "shield found" rather than "shield **is** found" wouldn't you? Same idea here.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14512/5010

Comment: Thanks both of you for the fruitful comments, spot on. Yet I still wonder, isn't the expression itself usually a part of any particular terminology, like "ryōkai" is mainly of military?

Comment: It *can* be used in military contexts too, but I don't think it's a "militarily term". There is nothing wrong with using it in pure academic contexts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is the name of the abbreviated writing style used in newspapers?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14512/what-is-the-name-of-the-abbreviated-writing-style-used-in-newspapers) (Game messages are not headlines but the grammar is essentially the same)